# Fraction with longer line

Tags: rules, fractions

I'm trying to display some axioms and operational rules with LaTeX.

Those are basically . They work quite well when used with frac, but it's not really nice, I'd like the fraction line to be a bit longer.

I know that sounds a bit vague, so here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve. I'm pretty sure that document has been typeset in LaTeX, so it should be doable.
[image: Photo of what I am trying to achieve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\newcommand\bigfrac[2]{%
  \begin{array}{c}
    #1 \\
    \hline
    #2
  \end{array}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to give it a little more space under the line (the letters over the arrows now almost touch it) so I tried: `\newcommand\bigfrac[2]{\begin{array}{c}#1\\\hline\vspace{1pt}#2\end{array}}` but that just increased the space between the two lines in the picture.

Comment: Add `\begingroup\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}` before `\begin{array}` and `\endgroup` after `\end{array}`. Load the **array** package.

Answer (score 23):

Here's an extended version of `\frac`, supporting an optional argument for a wider line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\frac}[3][0pt]{%
  {\begingroup\hspace{#1}#2\hspace{#1}\endgroup\over\hspace{#1}#3\hspace{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \frac{x}{y} \quad \frac[5pt]{x}{y}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can define your own frac command similar instead of redefining the existing `\frac`, also with a default value bigger than `0pt`.

The definition is similar to the definition in `amsmath.sty`, except that file is using `\@@over`.

Or, you could define your own macro using the original `\frac`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\widefrac}[3][5pt]{%
  \frac{\hspace{#1}#2\hspace{#1}}{\hspace{#1}#3\hspace{#1}}}
...
\widefrac{x}{y} ... \widefrac[8pt]{x+y}{y}
```

Comment: Note that the use of `\over` together with `amsmath` will lead to `Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \over`.

Comment: With `amsmath` the command `\@@over` can be used instead, exactly in the same way plus `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. `amsmath`defines: `\@saveprimitive\over\@@over`.

Comment: Why not restore the old `\frac` and use it here? Or use `\genfrac` provided by `amsmath`.

Comment: @Leo: added an example re-using `\frac`. Of course it could be done similar with `\genfrac`.

Answer (score 13):

In case you really want *fractions* with a longer line, you can just pad both numerator and denominator with spaces. (Padding the longer of the two would acually suffice.) `\frac{\ a\ }{\ b\ }` gives

[image]

For a longer line use, e.g., `\quad` instead of `\` .

Comment: OK, Stefan just posted a better version of this.

Comment: Stefan's solution is better, but your solution is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider to use a dedicated package to write your axioms; the [bussproofs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bussproofs) package could be an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\LArrow[1][a]{\xrightarrow{\phantom{a}#1\phantom{a}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{$x\LArrow x^\prime$}
  \UnaryInfC{$x+y\LArrow x^\prime$}
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To work with displayed math environments, a better option would be to use the [proof](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/proof) package. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*\PA{\phantom{a}}
\newcommand*\LArrow[1][a]{\xrightarrow{\PA#1\PA}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \infer{\PA x+y\LArrow x^\prime\PA}{x\LArrow x^\prime}
  \qquad
  \infer{\PA x+y\LArrow y^\prime\PA}{y\LArrow y^\prime}
  \qquad
  \infer{\PA x+y\, \downarrow\PA}{x\,\downarrow}
  \qquad
  \infer{\PA x+y\, \downarrow\PA}{y\,\downarrow}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks better, but I don't need more functionality than the answer above provided. Plus, I can't get it to work in a displaymath environment.

Comment: Interesting ! a discover for me

Comment: @Tim van Dalen: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the `\phantom{}` command, which renders the exact whitespace the exact same size as  its argument.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align*}
\varphi &= 1+ \frac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{\varphi}}\\[.5cm]
%
%
\varphi &= 1+ \frac{ \phantom{\longrightarrow} 1 \phantom{\longrightarrow} }{1 
+ \cfrac{1}{\varphi}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which returns

[image]